# Suzuki TU250X motorcycle only cranks when engine turned over by pushing in gear (electronic ignition)

Tags: motorcycle, starter, suzuki, relay

I have a 2000 Suzuki TU250x. It's had a intermittent problem using the electronic ignition to start the bike. Turn the key, hold in the clutch, lift kickstand, click the fuel pump relay switch, hear the fuel pump come on, hit the start switch and nothing. Put the bike in 1st roll it backwards popping the clutch, hit the start switch and it will crank 50% and run fine 100% of time.

I charged the battery
Replaced the starter and tried with same result using OEM Relay
Replaced the starter and tried with same result using Replacement Style Relay